# Unable to login from any other port and device except origin 8100 ionic application

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created ionic application. I can run it on browser with port 8100. 
But, unable to login from simulator or any other port. I have used httpClient to get hearder. Could you please guide me?

Here is my code calling API.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { mcsConfig } from "../../oracle_mobile_cloud_config";
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
// Alternative use
import {Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { User } from '../models/user';

import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
import { presentAlert } from "../utils/ui-utility.service";
import { IMCS, INetworkResponse } from 'mcs';
import * as mcssdk from 'mcs';
import { ReportItem } from '../models/ReportItem';
import { utils } from 'protractor';

const TOKEN_KEY = 'auth-token';

 // Alternative use
 var careheaders = new Headers();
 careheaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OraclemcsService {
  fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
  mcs: IMCS = mcssdk;
  authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  public userProfile;
  public lovActivityCode;
  public lovObsCode;
  public lovVesselCode;
  public lovYardCode;
  public lovDepartCode;

  public cookie;

  constructor(private storage: Storage
    , private plt: Platform
    , public loadingController: LoadingController
    , private httpClient: HttpClient

    , private http: HTTP
    //, private https: Http

    , private transfer: FileTransfer
    , public alertController: AlertController

  ) {
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
      //this.checkToken();
      this.mcs.init(mcsConfig);
      this.userProfile, this.lovActivityCode, this.lovObsCode, this.lovVesselCode, this.lovYardCode, this.lovDepartCode, this.cookie = {};
    });
  }
  checkToken() {
    this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY).then(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.authenticationState.next(true);
      }
    })
  }

  /**
   * on login initialize lov
   * login to oracle idcs
   * @param username 
   * @param password 
   */
  login(username: String, password: String) {
    if(username === undefined || username === '' || password === undefined || password === null){
      presentAlert("No username or password", this.alertController);
      return;
    }

    this.mcs.mobileBackend.setAuthenticationType(this.mcs.AUTHENTICATION_TYPES.oauth);
    this.mcs.mobileBackend.authorization.authenticate(username, password).then(
      () => {
        return Promise.all([
          this.mcs.mobileBackend.customCode.invokeCustomCodeJSONRequest(mcsConfig.environment + '_api_care/lovs?code_table_name=activity_code', 'GET', null)
          , this.mcs.mobileBackend.customCode.invokeCustomCodeJSONRequest(mcsConfig.environment + '_api_care/lovs?code_table_name=observation_code', 'GET', null)
          , this.mcs.mobileBackend.customCode.invokeCustomCodeJSONRequest(mcsConfig.environment + '_api_care/lovs?code_table_name=vessel_code', 'GET', null)
          , this.mcs.mobileBackend.customCode.invokeCustomCodeJSONRequest(mcsConfig.environment + '_api_care/lovs?code_table_name=yard_code', 'GET', null)
          , this.mcs.mobileBackend.customCode.invokeCustomCodeJSONRequest(mcsConfig.environment + '_api_care/lovs?code_table_name=from_department_code', 'GET', null)
        ]).then((values) => {
          this.lovActivityCode = values[0].data.items;
          this.lovObsCode = values[1].data.items;
          this.lovVesselCode = values[2].data.items;
          this.lovYardCode = values[3].data.items;
          this.lovDepartCode = values[4].data.items;
        });
      }
    ).then(() => {
      console.log('test2' + username + password);
      this.getUserRole();
      this.authenticationState.next(true);
    }).catch(err => {
      presentAlert(err.data.error_description, this.alertController);
    });

  }



  logout() {
    this.mcs.mobileBackend.authorization.logout();
    this.authenticationState.next(false);
  }

  /**
   * get oracle mcs header to append
   */ 
  getMcsHeaders() {
    var cheaders = {};
    for (let key in this.mcs.mobileBackend.getHttpHeaders()) {
      cheaders[key] = this.mcs.mobileBackend.getHttpHeaders()[key];
    }
    return cheaders;
  } 

  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.authenticationState.value;
  }

  /**
   *  return observable
   */ 
  getUserRole() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.mcs.mobileBackend.getPlatformUrl('users/me'), { headers: this.getMcsHeaders() }).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  } 

  getProfile() {
    return this.mcs.mobileBackend.customCode
      .invokeCustomCodeJSONRequest(mcsConfig.environment + '_api_care/my/profile', 'GET', null);
  }

  /**
   * return observable
   * @param userProfile 
   */
  updateProfile(userProfile) {
    return this.httpClient.patch(this.mcs.mobileBackend.getCustomCodeUrl(mcsConfig.environment + '_api_care/my/profile'), userProfile, { headers: this.getMcsHeaders() });
  }

  setProfile(userProfile) {
    console.log("inside set profile");
    this.userProfile = userProfile;
  }

  getReportList(offset: number = 0, limit: number = mcsConfig.rowLimit) {
    let queryParam = '?offset=' + (offset * limit) + '&limit=' + limit;
    return this.mcs.mobileBackend.customCode
      .invokeCustomCodeJSONRequest(mcsConfig.environment + '_api_care/my/incidents' + queryParam, 'GET', null);
  }

  getReportDetail(id: string) {
    return this.mcs.mobileBackend.customCode
      .invokeCustomCodeJSONRequest(mcsConfig.environment + '_api_care/my/incidents/' + id, 'GET', null);
  }

  createReportDetail(detail: ReportItem) {
    console.log('test' + JSON.stringify(detail));
    return this.mcs.mobileBackend.customCode
      .invokeCustomCodeJSONRequest(mcsConfig.environment + '_api_care/my/incidents', 'POST', detail);

  } 

  uploadReportPhoto(fileUrl, id: number) {
    var headerArr = this.getMcsHeaders();
    headerArr['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream';

    id = id + 1;
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: 'file',
      fileName: 'name.jpg',
      headers: headerArr
    }

    return this.fileTransfer.upload(fileUrl, this.mcs.mobileBackend.getCustomCodeUrl(mcsConfig.environment + '_api_care/my/latest_incident/photo' + (id == 1 ? '' : id)), options);

  }

  getLovActivityCode() {
    return this.lovActivityCode;
  }

  getLovObsCode() {
    return this.lovObsCode;
  }

  getLovVesselCode() {
    return this.lovVesselCode;
  }

  getLovYardCode() {
    return this.lovYardCode;
  }

  getLovDepartCode() {
    return this.lovDepartCode;
  }

}
```

When I run on emulator, the error show as below : 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: This is cors issue. check my answer

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari, Did you erase your answer? I tried with native http. the error has changed to this ``` ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'error_description' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'error_description' of undefined
    at main.js:9151
```

Comment: can you update your question. how you are using native http ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should allow Cross Origin request at receiving server as well, If it is a post call then receiver might not accept it because of the fact it is coming from some unknown origin.

To work through it, Allow receiver to accept cross origin request.

Example -

1. App Side

   ```
   < access origin="*" / >
   < access origin="http://*" / >
   < access origin="https://*" / >
   ```
2. In Java REST API's we use annotation as given below :

   ```
   @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
   ```

You can check for your code , or share it here.